# Update Cache after POST and Update using Output Cache .net core 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have implemented a custom policy for my .net core 7 web api using Output Cache which serves as the base policy for all controllers

```
services.AddCors();
services.AddOutputCache(opt=>
{
   opt.AddBasePolicy(OutputCachePolicy.Instance);
});
```

I want to update or refresh the cache whenever a new record is added or updated, but dont know how achieve this

Comment: Do you mean when you manipulate record in db, You also want to refresh the cache in the same time? In my opinion, You can try to use MediatR, Please refer to this [Docs](https://code-maze.com/cqrs-mediatr-in-aspnet-core/).

Comment: Sorry please am actually using OutPut Caching not Response Caching

Comment: In Output cache, There is a new feature called `Tag`, You can create another endpoint that clears the cache for any entries associated with that "Tag", Please refer to this [demo](https://www.honlsoft.com/blog/2022-09-24-output-caching-in-asp-net-core).  But in my opinion, Memory cache is more easy to achieve it.